# How to check an Outlook custom property is available via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-calendar

I added a custom property to an Event using an `office.js` add-in.

I tried to get that custom property's value using  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AQMkADU2OWFjYTF..AAAA==?singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 myCusPropId ')` but it is return an error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "PropertyId values may only be in one of the following formats: 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName', 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id propertyId' or 'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c57cd272-2c10-4721-b48e-1c27117ea34f",
      "date": "2019-09-27T10:23:03"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I retrieve `myCusPropId`?

here is office.js code

```js
const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(asyncResult => {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        let customProps = asyncResult.value; 
        customProps.set("myCusProp", "google.com");
        customProps.saveAsync(asyncResult => {
          if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {            
             item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(asyncResult => {
              const customProps = asyncResult.value;
              const myCusProp= customProps.get("myCusProp"); 
            })
          }});}});
```

Comment: It should be: `($filter=id eq 'String 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 Name myCusPropId')` Please note `Name` keyword before name of your property. Also, avoid extra spaces like you had in `myCusPropId '`

Comment: @Ivan Franjic . i followed the way. i ran into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166439/singlevalueextendedproperties-property-is-missing-when-expanding-outlook-event-i

Comment: Try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AQMkADU2OWFjYTF..AAAA==?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusPropId')`. filter=PropertyId instead of id.

Comment: tried  this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AQMkADU2OWFjYTF..AAAA==?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusPropId'`  and it gave bad request `{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Parsing Select and Expand failed.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "dd23f71e-9ab4-4137-9a3a-1d01b647f6fc",
      "date": "2019-10-08T06:21:21"
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the [`$expand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) query param and your id is malformed. The correct call phototype looks like this:

```
GET /me/events/{id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{prop_id}')
```

Note the `?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties` rather than `?singleValueExtendedProperties`.

For the property itself, you're missing the `Name` segment:

```
String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusPropId
```

So the final URI would be:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AQMkADU2OWFjYTF..AAAA==?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusPropId')`

Comment: I just tried this way but the response does not have custom property details. i created a new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166439/singlevalueextendedproperties-property-is-missing-when-expanding-outlook-event-i

Comment: is this 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 guid is correct ?

Comment: Yes. Please add the code you're using to add the data via Office.js.