# Expanding singleValueExtendedProperty not working when retrieving Event details

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to retrieve custom property value for an event using Microsoft Graph. 
The custom property was created by an Outlook Office.js Add-ing

Here is request

```
/v1.0/me/events/{id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusProp')
```

This returns a successful response from Graph but it does not return the `singleValueExtendedProperty`. The Outlook add-in, however, is still able to retrieve the property value from the same Event.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{id}')/events/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"SdXmMkSN8kCNtzTsQ4x1lwAD7sMWVg==\"",
  "id": "{id}",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-09-30T10:12:34.110571Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-09-30T10:23:57.8338159Z",
  "changeKey": "SdXmMkSN8kCNtzTsQ4x1lwAD7sMWVg==",
  "categories": [],
  "originalStartTimeZone": "blah blah",
  "originalEndTimeZone": "blah blah Standard Time",
  "iCalUId": "040000008...EBBE4999DC5A61D31AC544",
  "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
  "isReminderOn": true,
  "hasAttachments": false,
  "subject": "WWW-002",
  "bodyPreview": "rt",
  "importance": "normal",
  "sensitivity": "normal",
  "isAllDay": false,
  "isCancelled": false,
  "isOrganizer": true,
  "responseRequested": true,
  "seriesMasterId": null,
  "showAs": "busy",
  "type": "singleInstance",
  "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AQMkADU2OWFjYTFjLWNkMGYtNDdlNS1hNDIxLWIxYjlmY...DqyJu%2FWyzJk6m5v0MbSs7lwcASdXmMkSN8kCNtzTsQ4x1lwAAAgENA...AD7q52owAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
  "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
  "recurrence": null,
  "responseStatus": {
    "response": "organizer",
    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div>rt</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-09-19T02:30:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-09-19T03:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "location": {
    "displayName": "",
    "locationType": "default",
    "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
    "address": {},
    "coordinates": {}
  },
  "locations": [],
  "attendees": [],
  "organizer": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "Info a",
      "address": "name@domain.com"
    }
  }
}
```

----Update 1 - office.js code-----

This is office-js/outlook-add-in code reference above.
The custom property value can be read here without an issue.

```js
const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(asyncResult => {
    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        let customProps = asyncResult.value;
        customProps.set("myCusProp", "google.com");
        customProps.saveAsync(asyncResult => {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(asyncResult => {
                    const customProps = asyncResult.value;
                    const myCusProp = customProps.get("myCusProp");
                })
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the code you're using to set the value in Office.js

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  I  have added the office.js code  as update to question

Comment: here i added custom property through the outlook web(OWA) . if i add custom property through the COM add-in (Outlook Plugin), then singleValueExtendedProperties can be retrieved using the same graph api mentioned in question

Comment: Can you try seeing if the property was set on _any_ events? `/me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusProp' and and ep/value ne null)`

Comment: it gives me error  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusProp' and and ep/value ne null)' .  `error is {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid filter clause",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2805f5d3-d7ff-476a-bb17-48839603ed42",
      "date": "2019-10-08T13:39:12"
    }
  }
}  `

Comment: however `@SureshGowtham S` answer is giving all singleValueExtendedProperties

Comment: @Marc LaFleur there is additional 'and' in your query. it should be /me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name myCusProp' and ep/value ne null)

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4505745/cannot-save-meeting-as-draft-in-outlook-for-mac-using-office-js-api):

```
id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-<add-in id from manifest>'
```

Instead of `myCusProp` use `cecp-/* add-in id from manifest */`

Add-in id is the guid from manifest, this response has a custom properties as JSON.

Comment: i didnt found this link . thanks.  but my question is  based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132732/how-to-check-an-outlook-custom-property-is-available-via-microsoft-graph?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: this answer is working but it is giving all custom properties in array

Comment: after parsing the response you get a JSON representing the entire custom property map, so you can access the required property `myCustomPropertyResponse.myCusProp`