# Can't retrieve outlook add-in custom properties from graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-calendar

I need to save a custom property from my outlook add-in and retrieve the this value from graph Api.

I followed MS documentation, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166439/expanding-singlevalueextendedproperty-not-working-when-retrieving-event-details) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132732/how-to-check-an-outlook-custom-property-is-available-via-microsoft-graph?answertab=votes#tab-top).

I store the custom property with office.js methods `loadCustomPropertiesAsync` and `customProps.saveAsync`

I have checked the value is correctly stored to custom properties (I can read it from add-in when I come back to event)

When I try to check the value from graph API, the event is returned without custom props.

here is the request I use :

```
{{endpoint}}/Users/bc2d0290-xxx-4041d2d39b66/Events/AAMkADI1YTJjZTI1LWM4YjUtNxxxTvAAA=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-myAddInManifestId')
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The request looks correctly. What platform are you seeing this (Windows Outlook/OWA/Mac/iOS/Android etc)? And are you seeing this as organizer or attendee?  In some cases, changes via API do not sync immediately and so the properties may not be on the server yet (via the graph call).

Comment: I use OWA on Mac (Chrome) and I use organizer

Comment: Do you see any error in console when you run the request ?

Comment: yes there are errors but I don't know if there are about my subject. ` Refused to prefetch content from 'https://outlook-1.cdn.office.net/owamail/20210614002.09/scripts/owa.1294.js'` and some errors 400 http errors like this `https://outlook.office365.com/OWS/beta/Location/locationmap?Latitude=48.8579&Longitude=2.2793&Address=null&Culture=fr-FR&Width=64&Height=64&n=603&cv=cFOHd%2FMeKTxvgdAzBdszLe.603`

Comment: While making the request, Could you please confirm if all the alphabets in Addin Manifest Id are in lowercase?

Comment: sorry for my late answer : yes Addin Manifest Id is all lowercase

Comment: Hey @Hepatus. Can you please share us a code snippet which reproduces this issue? We will investigate the same.

Comment: I have a side question - how is the GUID {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} determined? The documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#:~:text=Valid%20id%20formats%20for%20single,Expand%20table) says _namespace_, but _what/whose_ namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
I use custom properties to enrich appointements with conference room.

I tried to retrieve custom props on my server from room eventId instead of organizer eventId